# Getting access to Java compiler symbol table

Tags: java, compiler-construction, symbol-table

I was wondering if it is possible to gain access to the Java compiler's symbol table in human readable form.  Is there a command or something similar to run in terminal when I compile a Java file? Or, is there a plugin or something similar for Eclipse or Intellij to gain access to it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked java reflection package. It is a standard package which allow you browsing objects and methods.

Comment: @Serge What does this have to do with what OP wants?

Comment: Compilers build symbol tables internally, and normally they don't save them after compilation is done.  The entire symbol table may not even exist in memory all at once; a compiler can add local variables to it when compiling a method, but then remove them (to save memory) once the method is done.  I don't see a common Java option to dump this info out while compiling.  It might help if you tell us exactly what kind of info you're looking for.

Comment: P.S. If you're interested in knowing how the innards of the compiler work--I believe the "javac" source is available, so in theory you could grab that, find out where it's handling the symbol tables, add some statements to dump some info, and build your own version of javac.  Obviously that is not trivial.

Comment: @QBrute, As far as i understood from the question, OP wants to traverse symbols in the symbol table, which reflect provides. However, if he/she really wants to know how the stuff is organized by the java compiler  in byte codes, i am taking my suggestion back.

Comment: @Serge Reflection doesn't provide any such thing. The Java compiler's symbol table is only present at compile time.  Reflection is only present at runtime.

Comment: @Serge And your suggestion *only* applies to 'how the stuff is organised by the compiler in the byte codes', which he *isn't* asking.